# Insert a Locally stored .svg into html

Tags: html, image, storage, local

I'm trying to put a logo on my home screen using html. This logo is a locally stored .svg file. I'm new to coding.

I input this code:

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Solo Scriptura Homepage</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Homepage.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <header>
        <img src="logo v2.svg" alt="My Logo"/>
      </header>
      <main></main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Resultingly, my alt text shows up as well as the little icon that means they can't load your image.

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all HTML tags.

Comment: I highly recommend to avoid whitespace in filenames. Quite often you need to encode these. When replacing these `to something like `ogo-v2.svg` you're on the safe side. But quite likely the path/URL is not correct. Check you devtools console for errors. Otherwise your svg may also reference an external `<image>`  that's blocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because your code does not define the path to the image file. For the browser to find the image, you need to define the right path for the image (the logo) to be recognized.

Say for instance your image(logo) is stored in a folder called images. Your code should look like this:

```
<img src="images/logo v2.svg" alt="My Logo"/>
```

And if the image (the logo) file is not saved in a folder. Save it in a folder and call the image path like the example above.